# backbone structure / collections / views passing and returning data

Tags: backbone.js

So I am putting together a very simple app and have got a bit stuck.

So far I have my router

```
 var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

routes:{
    "":"home"
},

initialize:function () {
    // Handle back button throughout the application
    $('.back').live('click', function(event) {
        window.history.back();
        return false;
    });
    this.firstPage = true;
    this.products = new Products();

},

home:function () {
    var view = new HomeView({collection:this.products});

// render the view when the collection is loaded
this.products.on("renderCompleted:Products", function() {

    //alert("ff");
    view.render();
});



// fetch should trigger "reset" when complete
this.products.fetch();
}
```

my model

```
var Product=Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        id:"",
        name:'',
        longName:'',
        productID:''
    }
});

return Product;
```

my collection

```
   var Products=Backbone.Collection.extend({

      // Book is the model of the collection
      model:Product,

      fetch:function(){
        var self=this;
        var tmpItem;
        //fetch the data using ajax

          var jqxhr = $.getJSON("data/product.json")
          .success(function(data, status, xhr) { 

            $.each(data.data.productTypeList, function(i,item){


              tmpItem=new Product({id:item.id,name:item.name,longName:item.longName, productID:i});
              self.add(tmpItem);

            });

            self.trigger("fetchCompleted:Products");

          })

      }

});

return Products;
```

and my view

var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({

```
template: _.template(homeViewTemplate),

    render:function (eventName) {
    //$(this.el).html(this.template());

     this.$el.empty();
  //compile template using the data fetched by collection
  this.$el.append(this.template({data:this.collection.toJSON()}));

  console.log("test" + this.collection.get('data'));

    return this;
}
```

the homeViewTemplate call has this HTML

```
  <ul >
           <% for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
                  <% var item = data[i]; %>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#products/list/<%= item.productID%>"><%= item.longName %></a>
                  </li>
            <% } %>
    </ul>
```

you can see from the router that on init this.Products is created of the collection

then when home is called it runs the view.

I dont think anything is passed from the collection to the view though and I am not sure how this is done? Is my collection setup wrong? - do I have to call fetch and pass that to the view?

Any help is appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> do I have to call fetch and pass that to the view?

You have to call fetch, and have its success callback trigger `view.render`.  You could do that using the `success` option of the JQuery call; or using the `reset` event, which `collection.fetch` normally calls.  I'd suggest putting `collection.reset` inside your custom `fetch`:

```
// get the data an an array of models
var models = data.data.productTypeList.map(function(item) {
    return new Product({id:item.id,name:item.name,longName:item.longName, productID:i});
});

// populate the collection
self.reset(models);
```

And then in the "home" route, call `fetch` and then call `render` on the callback:

```
home:function () {
    var view = new HomeView({collection:this.products});

    // render the view when the collection is loaded
    this.products.on("reset", function() {
        view.render();
    });

    // fetch should trigger "reset" when complete
    this.products.fetch();
}
```

Comment: thanks this is good.. i am have just updated the question based on your advice as I am still not completely there

Comment: @Dan I think you meant `fetchCompleted:Products` and `renderCompleted:Products` to be the same string, right?  They have to match.  Also, I think to trigger custom events from the collection, you have to extend it using `_.extend(this.products, Backbone.Events)`: http://backbonejs.org/#Events

Comment: haha thanks.. its been a long day.. Have actually done it slightly differently. but at least its working